# jQuery - html(this); removes the (this) div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a div change it's content with the clicked image.

I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.smallImg').click(function(){
       $('.bigImg').html(this);
   });

});//

<div class='smallImg'><img src='imgHere'></div>
<div class='bigImg'></div>
```

It's working, but for some reason, it's removing the clicked image. Why, and how would I make it not to?

Comment: What code? There is no more code..

Comment: Why are you using ```this```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's removed because the dom node is moved. You can prevent that by cloning the dom-node:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.smallImg').click(function(){
       $('.bigImg').html($(this).clone());
   });

});//
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('.bigImg').html(this);
```

try

```
$('.bigImg').html(this.html);
```

Remember 'this' refers to the object, which contains all of the data (including HTML) about the object so you need to specifically call out the data you want.

Comment: `this.html` should be a function call I think... `this.html()`